# How does Whatsapp find receiver's IP address?

Tags: whatsapp

Image A sends a Whatsapp message to B. B is offline. B will receive the mesage when he is online. I am interested in how Whatsapps finds the IP address of B?
One more question: How Whatsapp calls work? 
For example, I am making a call to C. Call goes to Whatsapp server then what?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did approximately 2-3 hours of research. I could not find an exact answer to my question. If you know any resource then you are welcome to suggest. Downvoting is not a solution

Comment: You're getting down-voted because your question is too broad and doesn't fit within the scope of allowed questions that is defined in the [help/on-topic].  You're asking for someone to completely explain the protocols behind a proprietary app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They don't need to know the IP address of the sender or the receiver. The message is sent between 2 accounts regardless if the receiver is online. When the receiver gets internet connection he's able to view the messages that are registered to that account, and then they're saved offline to the phone.

The protocol they're using is called **Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol (XMPP)** and you can read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP)

Comment: If B is offline, how message can be saved to his device?

Comment: @MuradZulfugarov it doesn't. As I wrote in the answer, the message is saved on the Whatsapp server and references the message to the receiver account. When you go online, then you'll be able to view the new message on your account, and then it's saved offline to your device.

Comment: Nice. My question is that when B goes online how Whatsapp finds out his IP address to send message to him?

Comment: @MuradZulfugarov It doesn't care about the IP address at all. To over-simplify things, every Whatsapp account has a flag called "online" which says true or false. If the flag is false when sending the message is simply stored on the Whatsapp server until the flag switches to true, at which point a request is sent from the device to retrieve all the messages. It's like a carrier wanting to deliver a package, he knocks on your door to see if you're home (online), if you're not, he puts the package in the mailbox (Whatsapp server).

Comment: Thanks. Nice explanation. That was what I wanted to know.

Comment: @MuradZulfugarov, if you like this answer, consider up voting it.